page not found after custom permalink
I used croccoblock jetengine plugin to make 4 custom post types as this :
1- Explanation (for school subjects)
2- Term (first and second)
3- Class (first class, second .....upto sixth class)
4- Country Curriculum (British, Qatar, UAE)
then made these relations between post types:
1- Curriculum -> Explanation
2- Class -> Explanation
3- Term -> Explanation
so when I create a post of "Explanation" post type, the same explanation may be found many times according to Term and Class and Curriculum. for example may the "Explanation" posts be like this :
1- Math (Term-> first, Class-> forth, Country Curriculum-> UAE)
2- Math (Term-> first, Class-> sixth, Country Curriculum-> British)
3- Physics  (Term-> second, Class-> sixth, Country Curriculum-> Qatar)
etc
but the post permalink is like this :
https://mywebsite.com/explanation/post_name
and I need it to be like this (for example):
https://mywebsite.com/UAE/fisrt_class/second/explanation/math
so I made this code to make a custom permalink for post of "Explanation"
post type according to its relations and I can't set those relations inside a custom permalink from (Settings -> Permalink) because they are not saved as meta data of posts (saved only in table in database):
function get_post_type_relation($relation)
{
    $relations_manager = jet_engine()->relations;
    $post_types = $relations_manager->data->db->query_cache['post_types'];

    $relation_post_types = array_filter($post_types, function ($post_type) {
        return $post_type['status'] === 'relation';
    });

    $relation_post_types_info = array_map(function ($post_type) {
        return [
            'id' => $post_type['id'],
            'name' => unserialize($post_type['labels'])['name']
        ];
    }, $relation_post_types);

    $formatted_relations_array = array_reduce($relation_post_types_info, function ($carry, $item) {
        $parts = explode(' to ', $item['name']);
        if (count($parts) === 2) {
            $child = $parts[1];
            $parent = $parts[0];
            $carry[$child]['Relations']['as_child'][] = [
                'id' => $item['id'],
                'parent' => $parent,
                'db_relation_table' => 'jet_rel_' . $item['id']
            ];
        }
        return $carry;
    }, []);

    return $formatted_relations_array[$relation] ?? [];
}

function get_relation_parent_postid($relation, $child_post_id, $parent_item)
{

    $relation = 'Explanation';
    $post_type_relsult = get_post_type_relation($relation);
    $post_type_relations = $post_type_relsult['Relations']['as_child'];
    $relation_db = '';
    foreach ($post_type_relations as $relation) {

        if ($relation['parent'] == $parent_item) {
            $relation_db = $relation['db_relation_table'];
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($relation_db != '') {
        global $wpdb;
        $relation_db = $wpdb->prefix . $relation_db;



        $table_exists = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SHOW TABLES LIKE %s", $relation_db));

        if ($table_exists) {
            $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT parent_object_id FROM $relation_db WHERE child_object_id = %d", $child_post_id);
        } else {

            $relation_db = $wpdb->prefix . 'jet_rel_default';

            $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT parent_object_id FROM $relation_db WHERE child_object_id = %d", $child_post_id);
        }

        $parent_object_id = $wpdb->get_var($query);

        return $parent_object_id;
    }
}


function custom_explanation_permalink($post_link, $post)
{
    $relation = 'explanation';
    if ($post->post_type == $relation) {

        $explanation_result = get_post_type_relation($relation);
        // Replace these with the actual IDs
        $curriculum_id = get_relation_parent_postid($explanation_result, $post->ID, 'Curriculum'); // Replace with your curriculum ID
        $class_id = get_relation_parent_postid($explanation_result, $post->ID, 'Class');; // Replace with your class ID
        $term_id = get_relation_parent_postid($explanation_result, $post->ID, 'Term');; // Replace with your term ID

        if (!empty($curriculum_id) && !empty($class_id) && !empty($term_id)) {
            // Get the post slugs using the IDs
            $curriculum_slug = get_post_field('post_name', $curriculum_id);
            $class_slug = get_post_field('post_name', $class_id);
            $term_slug = get_post_field('post_name', $term_id);

            $new_slug = $curriculum_slug . '/' . $class_slug . '/' . $term_slug . '/explanation';

            // Replace the placeholders in the permalink with the actual slugs
            $post_link = str_replace('explanation', $new_slug, $post_link);
        }
    }
    return urldecode($post_link);;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'custom_explanation_permalink', 10, 2);

and everything works well but when I open the new url of the post it shows this message :
Page not found
It looks like nothing was found at this location.
how to fix please

If you re save your permalinks is it fixing it ? Flush permalinks after creating new post i guess should do it. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/

I used this function (flush_rewrite_rules();) before  (return urldecode($post_link);) but still shows this error "The page can’t be found. t looks like nothing was found at this location."
